Show that the kernel of a homomorphic function f is a normal subgroup of the kernel of the homomorphic composition g of f.
So I have this question that states:
Let $H,K$ and $N$ be groups and let $f∶H \rightarrow K$ and $g∶K \rightarrow N$ be homomorphisms. The composition $g \circ f$ is also a homomorphism.
a.) Show that the kernel $ker(f)$ is a normal subgroup of $ker(g \circ f)$.
b.) Suppose that the order of $H$ is a prime $p$ and suppose also that $g \circ f$ is injective. Prove that there is an element in $K$ of order $p$.
My solution is as follows:
a.) We can construct a well-defined map $\varphi: ker(g \circ f) \rightarrow K$. We know that the restriction of a homomorphism is a homomorphism. Since $ker(g \circ f)$ is a (normal) subgroup of $H$, then $\varphi$ is a homomorphism. Now, $ker(\varphi) = ker(f)$ since $ker(f) \subseteq ker(g \circ f)$ and $\varphi (ker(f)) \mapsto e_K$. By the Homomorphism theorem, $ker(f)$ is a normal subgroup of $ker(g \circ f)$.
b.) If $\#H = p$ and $p$ is prime, then it must contain a generator of order $p$ generating $H$. Since $g \circ f$ is injective, that implies that all elements of $H$ must be mapped to the elements in $K$, all of which must in turn be mapped to the elements in $N$. This means that $f$ must map each element in $H$ to a unique element $K$, but must also map to all elements in $K$. Otherwise, if any element in $H$ were not to be mapped to $K$, then it would not be mapped to $N$ and $g \circ f$ would not be injective. Hence, $g \circ f$ is isomorphic, and $K$ contains the generator of order $p$.
Specific doubts: for a.) is the map phi that I constructed a valid way to prove the question? For b.) does g of f being injective validate the fact that the function f must be bijective?
Any feedback is appreciated!

@hff1 Is the title better now? I couldn't find any question tackling exactly what I want.

@hff1 ohhh, I want my proof to be verified. Well it's two things; for a.) is the map phi that I constructed a valid way to prove the question? For b.) does g of f being injective validate the fact that the function f must be bijective? I apologize for the confusion !

You never define $\varphi$. You just say that "we can construct a well-defined map", but you never say what it is (or why you need to worry about "well-definedness"). You ask about the map $\varphi$ you constructed... but you never constructed. You never told us what it is. I suspect you wanted $\varphi$ to be the restriction of $f$ to $\ker(g\circ f)$, but you never said so.

Ad a)
What is ker(ker($g \circ f$))? Normally the "ker" operator is applied on a homomorphism (from $H$), not on a subgroup of $H$.
But this claim can be proved much easier. It's well-known (or easy to see), that ker($f$) is normal subgroup of $H$. And because ker($f$) $\subseteq$ ker($g \circ f$), it's clear that this claim is true.

Yes, you're absolutely right. Your solution for a.) is much more straightforward. By ker(ker($g \circ f$)) I meant ker($\varphi$)!

Ad b)
The fact that $g \circ f$ is injective in general doesn't imply that $f$ is surjective or $g$ is injective. However, it implies that $f$ is injective, and this suffices to solve the problem.
You're right that $H$ contains a generator $x$ of order $p$ (and in fact $H$ is isomorphic to the $\mathbb{Z}_p$ group, where $x$ can be mapped to 1). Then order of $f(x)$ must divide $p$, and so it must be 1 or $p$. But element of order 1 is only the unit element, so if it is 1, then $f$ is constant, contradiction with $f$ beeing injective. Thus order of $f(x)$ is $p$, so $f(x)$ can be what we are looking for.
Any questions?

Thank you! Two more questions; what is an appropiate way to "contruct" the map phi as you mentioned in your comment? Assuming that I actually construct phi, does my argument, albeit being convoluted, still make sense?
